# Passing data via ng click into new view

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a list of items pulled from the API and shown like this:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="project in projects" class="item item-text-wrap no-padding" ng-if="projects">
    <li class="item item-icon-right" ng-click="newUpdatePage(project.project_name)">
        <h2>{{project.project_name}}</h2>
        <i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-right"></i>
    </li>
</ion-item>
```

What I want is that when clicking the list item, the ng click runs a function:

```
$scope.newUpdatePage = function (project_name) {
    $state.go('app.new_update');
}
```

That state then is just a normal state which shows a template page. However, on that template page I need to get that project_name value and eventually more data for posting a form. I can't figure out how to get the data from my original list items, into this new view which will be a form to post.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$scope.newUpdatePage = function (projectId) {
    $state.go('app.new_update', {projectId: projectId});
}
```

And in your new state/controller do:

```
myDataService.getById('Project', $stateParams.projectId)
```

Make sure that your new state has `projectId` as parameter in the definition